# Is there a way to obtain statevector results from pulse circuits in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, openpulse, dynamics

As shown in [Ref](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.09253), the amplitude of a pulse determines the rotation on the x-axis, while the angle determines the rotation on the z-axix. According to the paper, the author proved such results with pulse experiments and plot the results on the Bloch sphere.

[image: Experiment results in paper]

However, after reading the source code of this paper on Github. He utilized the following method to simulate pulse circuit.

```
from qiskit import pulse
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeManila
backend = FakeManila()
schedule1 = pulse.Schedule(name='angle_sampling')
drag1 = pulse.library.Drag(duration=duration, amp=amp, sigma=sigma, beta=beta, angle=angle)
schedule1 += pulse.Play(drag1, pulse.DriveChannel(0))
schedule1 += measure << 500
samples = [float(decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(0, 1000))/500)* np.pi for _ in range(500)]
schedule1_all = [schedule1.assign_parameters({angle: sample}, inplace = False) for sample in samples]
backend_sim = qd.DynamicsBackend.from_backend(backend, evaluation_mode='sparse')
solver_options = {"method": "statevector", "atol": 1e-6, "rtol": 1e-8}
backend_sim.set_options(solver_options=solver_options)
job = backend_sim.run(schedule1_all, shots=1024, meas_level=2, meas_return='avg')
```

Through such method, it seems impossible to capture statevector from the job result.
I wonder if there is any way to obtain the statevector of a pulse experiment?